Reference request on André Weil
Andre Weil is reported to have stated "La logique est l'hygiène des mathématiques." Where did he state this, if anywhere?

It is interesting to see a connection between Weyl and Weil.

@GeraldEdgar Or perhaps someone read Weil and then wrote Weyl, or vice versa; it's not that surprising, since they are more or less from the same period and both dealt with the philosophy of mathematics (the subject that lends itself most to aphorisms and anecdotes).

@njuffa "The earliest instance of this claim that I can find dates to 1958, ..." Did you find a quotable instance?

@njuffa So may I use something like "Logic is the hygiene which mathematics practices to keep its ideas healthy and strong."  Hermann Weyl - uncertain origin?

@njuffa So: Attributed to Hermann Weyl in Proceedings of the Second Symposium on Engineering Mathematics, p. 24?

@njuffa Are the last Morris Kline attributions kosher, as it were? That is my hunch, as I know Morris Kline as an eminent historian and  philosopher of mathematics, on account of his book Mathematics: the loss of certainty.

The earliest instance of the quote from the question that I can find is in English, and attributed to Hermann Weyl.
Morris Kline, "Critique of Modern Mathematics and an Alternative for High School Mathematics Curricula." In Proceedings of the Second Symposium on Engineering Mathematics, Ohio State University, March 6, 1958, pp. 17-27
Starting at the bottom of p. 23 and continuing on p. 24 (my bolding):

As Roger Bacon said, "Argument concludes a question ; but is does not make us feel certain, or acquiesce in the contemplation of truth, except the truth also be found to be so by experience." Let me cite some other wise advice in this connection. Three hundred years ago Galileo said, "Logic, it appears to me, teaches us how to test the conclusiveness of any argument or demonstration already discovered and completed ; but I do not believe that it teaches us to discover correct arguments and demonstrations." Pascal said, "Reason is the slow and torturous method by which those who do not know the truth discover it." The proper finesse, rather than logic, is what is needed to do the correct thing. Herman Weyl said, "Logic is the hygiene which mathematics practices to keep its ideas healthy and strong." If I may exaggerate slightly, I would put it that rigor is the gilt of the lily of real mathematics.

Morris Kline repeated the quote and attribution later the same year in the following publication, where it appears on p. 423:
Morris Kline, "The ancients versus the moderns, a new battle of the books." The Mathematics Teacher, Vol. 51, No. 6, Oct. 1958, pp. 418-427
Kline does not provide a citation for this quote. One could hypothesize that he read a publication by André Weil, that he later later modified and then misattributed to Hermann Weyl.
André Weil, "L’avenir des mathématiques." In François Le Lionnais (ed.), Les grands courants de la pensée mathématique. Marseille: Cahiers du Sud 1948, pp. 307-320
An authorized English translation of this became available a few years later:
André Weil (tr. Arnold Dresden), "The Future of Mathematics." The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 57, No. 5, May 1950, pp. 295-306
In the original publication Weil wrote:

Mais, si la logique est l’hygiène du mathématicien, ce n’est pas elle qui lui fournit sa nourriture; le pain quotidien dont il vit, ce sont les grands problèmes.

Google translation: "But if logic is the mathematician's hygiene, it is not logic that provides him with his food; the daily bread on which he lives is the great problems."
To me this reads more like Weil is referencing a previously existing aphorism about logic constituting the hygiene of mathematicians.
One could also speculate that Weil, Weyl, and Kline knew each other personally, and that this notion could have arisen in informal conversation or correspondence between them. Weyl worked at Princeton, New Jersey from 1933 to 1951, while during WW2 Kline was stationed just forty miles away in Belmar, New Jersey. Weil came to the United States in 1941 and stayed there until end of WW2. For a while he taught at Lehigh University in Pennsylvania, some 60 miles from Princeton.

Many thanks for this impressive reply which I only saw after my last comment above! Is «Herman Weyl said, "Logic is the hygiene which mathematics practices to keep its ideas healthy and strong."», or just the quote, on 23, 24 or both?

@Frode Alfson Bjørdal The quoted section starts on p 23, but the bolded sentence is entirely contained within p. 24. See Google's snippet here: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings/8rBPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22Logic+is+the+hygiene+which+mathematics+practices+to+keep+its+ideas+healthy+and+strong%22&dq=%22Logic+is+the+hygiene+which+mathematics+practices+to+keep+its+ideas+healthy+and+strong%22&printsec=frontcover

OK! :) Many thanks again for your splendid reply, and happy holidays!
